# Infinite Scroll in Ag-grid Details Grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

How to set infinite scroll/Pagination in the details grid. I'm using server side model for master and want to use infinite model for details. How to setup details grid detailCellRendererParams with infinite scroll row Data

Comment: Would it be possible to get code example? What means details grid and what stands for master?

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/

Comment: got it. Just edited the post with working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define in `detailGridOptions` infinite row model type & its properties:

```js
detailGridOptions: {
    ...
    rowModelType: 'infinite',
    // enable pagination
    pagination: true,
    // fetch 15 rows per at a time
    cacheBlockSize: 15,
    // display 10 lines per page
    paginationPageSize: 10,
    // how many rows to seek ahead when unknown data size.
    cacheOverflowSize: 2,
    // how many concurrent data requests are allowed.
    // default is 2, so server is only ever hit with 2 concurrent requests.
    maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests: 2,
    // how many rows to initially allow scrolling to in the grid.
    infiniteInitialRowCount: 1,
    // how many pages to hold in the cache.
    maxBlocksInCache: 2
}
```

The `infiniteDatasource` presents the way you can retrieve the data for detail part:

```js
getDetailRowData: (params) => {
    //Get grid api regarding current row 
    var detailGrid = gridOptions.api.getDetailGridInfo(params.node.id);
    //Simulation of server
    var server = new FakeServer(params.data.callRecords);
    //Preparation of data
    var datasource = new infiniteDatasource(server, params);
    detailGrid.api.setDatasource(datasource);
}
```

Please note that regarding the documantation:

> If you are an enterprise user you should consider using the Server-side row model instead of the infinite row model. It offers the same functionality with many more features.

Setting of Server-side row model should be similar to Infinite one.

[Working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/pxUYf7xVznwz6vU7grCi?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a bunch will try and let you know if I find any issues.

Comment: Also is there a way I access updated state/props inside the
detailCellRendererParams.getDetailRowData closure. Since it's bound once any updates to state/props are not reflected inside. Right now I'm sending in the data inside of the Master Row to access it inside getDetailRowData function.

Comment: Probably you will need to refresh the grid in order to go through getDetailRowData  again. While changing the data, you should probably consider using api.redrawRows(redrawRowsParams) /api.refreshCells(cellRefreshParams) functions to reflect the state change inside the grid.